# How can I split a cell in a pandas dataframe and keep the delimiter in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

| persons |
| --- |
| John New York |
| Janet New York |
| Mike Denver |
| Michelle Texas |

I want to split into 2 columns: person and city. I tried this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"persons": ["John New York", "Janet New York", "Mike Denver", "Michelle Texas"]})
df[["name", "city"]] = df.persons.str.split("New York", expand=True,)
```

and it gives me this:

```
          persons            name  city
0   John New York           John
1  Janet New York          Janet
2     Mike Denver     Mike Denver  None
3  Michelle Texas  Michelle Texas  None
```

What I want is to split by cities and keep the separator in the city column like this:

```
          persons            name  city
0   John New York           John   New York
1  Janet New York          Janet   New York 
2     Mike Denver     Mike Denver  None
3  Michelle Texas  Michelle Texas  None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with a capture group:

```
df[['name', 'city']] = df['persons'].str.split(r'(New York)', expand=True).iloc[:,:2]

print(df)

          persons            name      city
0   John New York           John   New York
1  Janet New York          Janet   New York
2     Mike Denver     Mike Denver      None
3  Michelle Texas  Michelle Texas      None
```

Read more on how it works [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split).

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thanks for teaching me about capture groups.